# electron sheetjs download generated file from JSON

Tags: file, vue.js, download, electron, sheetjs

I have an Electron app with VueJS and I try to download a generated XLS with sheetjs but the [provided](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/tree/master/demos/electron) workaround does not work in my case. Here is what I have been trying:

```
 exportData(id, type) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(type);

      (async () => {
        const data = await ProjectController.getProject(id);
        const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(JSON.parse(data.excel));
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console

        let wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "test");
        let o = dialog.showSaveDialog();
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(o);

        XLSX.writeFile(wb, o);

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        //console.log(file);
      })();
    }
```

In console I get the following error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: o.file.lastIndexOf is not a function`.

if I use the following code

```
  (async () => {
        const data = await ProjectController.getProject(id);

        const ws = (XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(
          JSON.parse(data.excel)
        ));

        let wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "test");


        const file = XLSX.write(wb, {
          bookType: "xlsx",
          type: "buffer",
          compression: true
        });

        let savePath = dialog.showSaveDialog({});
        XLSX.writeFile(file, savePath);

        fs.writeFileSync("test1.xlsx", file);


      })();
```

than the file will be downloaded inside of the root of project folder without no popup before. But I would like to be able to download this files in a chosen folder by user.

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "movie-translation-tool",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "i18n:report": "vue-cli-service i18n:report --src './src/**/*.?(js|vue)' --locales './src/locales/**/*.json'",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "main": "background.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "awesome-phonenumber": "^2.24.0",
    "core-js": "^3.4.3",
    "dropbox": "^4.0.30",
    "knex": "^0.20.3",
    "mssql": "^6.0.1",
    "objection": "^2.0.3",
    "pdf2json": "^1.2.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.1.1",
    "vee-validate": "^3.1.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vue-video-player": "^5.0.2",
    "vuetify": "^2.1.0",
    "vuetify-image-input": "^19.1.0",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^4.6.95",
    "@mdi/js": "^4.6.95",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "electron": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "^1.4.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "^0.6.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

How can I attach the file to the windows properly?

Comment: Does the save dialog pops up? Where do you use this function, on the main process or in the renderer process? Also, please update with your `package.json` contents.

Comment: with the first example I have the popup but nothing is getting saved, with second code snippet I have no popup and the file is gettings saved in my project root. Actually the `exportData` is a VUE method which is triggered on click button.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog method [`dialog.showSaveDialog`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowsavedialogbrowserwindow-options) returns a promise which resolves to an object, it does not return a string:

> #### [`dialog.showSaveDialog([browserWindow, ]options)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowsavedialogbrowserwindow-options)
>
> Returns `Promise<Object>` - Resolve with an object containing the
>   following:
>
> - `canceled` Boolean - whether or not the dialog was canceled.
> - `filePath` String (optional) - If the dialog is canceled, this will be `undefined`.
> - `bookmark` String (optional) `macOS` mas - Base64 encoded string which contains the security scoped bookmark data for the saved file.
>     `securityScopedBookmarks` must be enabled for this to be present. (For
>     return values, see table here.)

You have to `await` for [`dialog.showSaveDialog`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowsavedialogbrowserwindow-options) or use [`dialog.showSaveDialogSync`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowsavedialogsyncbrowserwindow-options) and also, you can make `exportData` to be asynchronous rather than creating an inner async function.

Try to refactor your code like this:

```js
async exportData(id, type) {
  const data = await ProjectController.getProject(id);
  const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(JSON.parse(data.excel));
  const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();

  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "test");

  let { filePath, canceled } = await dialog.showSaveDialog();

  if (!canceled) {
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, filePath);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is working nice with refactoring. Would be possible to push a given filename to the popup?

Comment: Yes you can use `defaultPath` option property to set the proposed filename or even path to the dialog (*for example `await dialog.showSaveDialog(null, { defaultPath: "Project-data.xls" })`*). *`defaultPath` String (optional) - Absolute directory path, absolute file path, or file name to use by default*.